# Doctrine inheritance mapping multiple entities on single table

Tags: oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing a translate system (not based on the existing ones because of some constraints).
I've got one class/table `Product` with default language (french) the others are in another table.

A super class named `TranslateProduct`, it will be abstract, it depends on the solution I'll find.

There is a class `EnProduct` for english product, `DeProduct` for german etc.

These classes are mapped on a single table named `translate_product`.

In the `translateProduct.orm.xml` I have this for the inheritance :

```
<discriminator-column name="translate_type" type="string" />
    <discriminator-map>
        <discriminator-mapping value="en" class="EnProduct" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="de" class="DeProduct" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="nl" class="NlProduct" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="it" class="ItProduct" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="es" class="EsProduct" />
    </discriminator-map>
```

So far it's ok but, **the thing I want to do is that each translate of product is in a single row.** for example :

I create an object :

```
$enProduct = new EnProduct(); 
$emProduct->setProductCode("123456");
$enProduct->setName("Door");

$em->persist($enProduct);
$em->flush();
```

In the database I'll have :

id | product_code | en_name

1  | 123456  | Door

[image]

I have mapped the variables name to `column` en_name and de_name
through the xml file

So now I want to get an object TranslateProduct with the Id = 1 and cast it to a `DeProduct` object the problem is the `discriminator-column` (translate_type) it is already set to `enProduct` and it's normally but how can I transform a single row in multiple objects of different types ?

I dont know if it was clear...

Comment: If you are using Doctrine2 you should consider using the doctine extensions from gedmo of the knp doctrine behaviors.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not looking for a existing translating system. I've looked at the gedmo extension, I think it'll import every translation in the origin table. The problem is that I have more then 5000 products joined to other tables.
So I want to have a default product table in French and one table with other languages.

Comment: If your default language is French, with gedmo, the base fields of your entity will be used and filled with French language. The other languages will be stocked in the "ext-translations" table, using one row per language per entity property translated.

Comment: So that's the problem I have 5 extra languages so : 5 x 5000
And when I want to get a English product, I will search for the french one and join it with the table of translations and find the translation in the 25 000 rows. There are other tables joined to the products that containes more then 100 000 rows per language. You see my problem ?

Comment: I see the problem Mirza. But looking for the translation isn't that cost extensive as when you use the translatable the way the doc tells : it looks for the "what-you-want-to-translate-object"'s id directly in the ext-translations table. It is an indexed column so research should be really quick. But it still may be too slow for your use case I guess.

Comment: I think it's quick if there is not much data on the database. In my case, I've other databases running on the same server. The thing I'm doing is a Webservice a GIS database is also behind. I'm trying to find a good ration between space and performance. 
There will a lot of request there. I have not calculated yet but I think about 300 000 - 500 000 requests per day only on this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't know if my question was really clear...
So I wanted to get from for example this row :

[image: row in database]

You can see that this row is an `EnProduct` object, but I want also get a `DeProduct` from this same row.

I did the inheritance like in the Doctrine documentation said (still single_table)

And in every repository class I put this code :

```
public function findOneByPk($id){
    $className = $this->getClassMetadata()->name;
    $fields = $this->getClassMetadata()->fieldNames;

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult($className, 'p');

    $sql = "Select ";
    foreach($fields as $column => $field){
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p', $column, $field);
        $sql .= "p.".$column. " as ".$field.", ";
    }

    $sql = trim($sql);
    $sql = trim($sql,",");

    $sql .= " FROM translate_product p";
    $sql .= " WHERE p.id=".$id;


    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

This will hydrate the right object.

**Edit:**

If using **PostgreSQL** database and using `camelcase` fields, you have to put **double-quotes** on the alias :

```
public function findOneByPk($id){
    $className = $this->getClassMetadata()->name;
    $fields = $this->getClassMetadata()->fieldNames;

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult($className, 'p');

    $sql = "Select ";
    foreach($fields as $column => $field){
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p', $column, $field);
        $sql .= 'p.'.$column. ' as "'.$field.'", ';
    }

    $sql = trim($sql);
    $sql = trim($sql,",");

    $sql .= " FROM translate_product p";
    $sql .= " WHERE p.id=".$id;


    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```